# Multi-clause AND query not working when there are more than two AND clauses

Tags: rally

I created a custom app for my company, and the query works fine as long as there are only two fields in it, once a third one is added, it returns no records:

For reference, I am querying STORIES and DEFECTS:

```
    var query = [];
var queryCriteria = buildQueryFilter(STORIES);
query[0] = {
    key   : STORIES,
    type  : "HierarchicalRequirement",
    fetch : "FormattedID,Name,Owner,SubProject,CreationDate,Release,Iteration,ScheduleState,State,Build,Parent",
    order : "FormattedID",
    query : queryCriteria
};

var queryCriteria = buildQueryFilter(DEFECTS);
if (!(showUserStoriesOnly)){
    query[1] = {
        key   : DEFECTS,
        type  : "defects",
        fetch : "FormattedID,Name,Owner,SubProject,CreationDate,Release,Iteration,ScheduleState,State,FixedInBuild,Requirement",
        order : "FormattedID",
        query : queryCriteria
    };
}

rallyDataSource.findAll(query, showResults);
```

**EDIT**: Here is some "abbreviated" code for the buildQueryFilter:

```
returnFilter += returnFilter.length === 0 ? '' : ' AND '
returnFilter += '(Iteration.Name = "' + filterIteration + '")';

returnFilter += returnFilter.length === 0 ? '' : ' AND '
returnFilter += '(ScheduleState = "' + filterScheduleState + '")';

returnFilter += returnFilter.length === 0 ? '' : ' AND '
returnFilter += '(Owner = \"__USER_NAME__\")';


returnFilter = '(' + returnFilter + ')';
```

When the "queryCriteria" is:

**Query (stories):**((Iteration.Name = "25 (10/02 - 10/16)") AND (ScheduleState = "Accepted"))

**Query (defects):**((Iteration.Name = "25 (10/02 - 10/16)") AND (ScheduleState = "Accepted"))

It works. But once I add a **3rd** field - and it does not matter what field, or what order - then it does not work anymore:

**Query (stories):**((Iteration.Name = "25 (10/02 - 10/16)") AND (ScheduleState = "Accepted") AND (Owner = "user@domain.com"))

**Query (defects):**((Iteration.Name = "25 (10/02 - 10/16)") AND (ScheduleState = "Accepted") AND (Owner = "user@domain.com"))

I've been looking over the documentation and this is supposed to work. I am not sure why it is not. Does anyone have a clue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [rally.sdk.util.Query](http://developer.rallydev.com/help/query) utility should help you build valid queries (the syntax can get pretty hard to read with all the nested () in large queries).

```
var queries = [
    'Iteration.Name = "' + filterIteration + '"',
    'ScheduleState = "' + filterScheduleState + '",
    'Owner = "__USER_NAME__"'
];
var queryFilter = rally.sdk.util.Query.and(queries);
var queryString = queryFilter.toString();

//queryString should be this:
//(((Iteration.Name = "25 (10/02 - 10/16)") AND (ScheduleState = "Accepted")) AND (Owner = "user@domain.com"))
```

Comment: Hi @kyle, actually the buildQueryFilter method is pretty simple, I just get values from the UI and build a string that is returned in the way I presented in the original post.

Comment: You're missing some parens.  Take a look at the parens in the queryFilter.toString() output in my example.  Your query should look like this: (((Iteration.Name = "25 (10/02 - 10/16)") AND (ScheduleState = "Accepted")) AND (Owner = "user@domain.com"))

Comment: Yeah. I tried playing with the parens myself but it did not work. I will try the Query object and will let you know. Thanks!